# Python, adding two values from two different dictionaries in a for loop if conditions are satisfied

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to know if there is a possible solution for my problem. I want add and return the integers from each dictionary if the string conditions 'Mars' and 'First' are satisfied. My for loop is not working, i need help. the printed value should be 230. Should I import a module or a package?

my code:

'''

```
   planets = {
  'Mercury':['Estimated travel duration time: 6.5 years','./static/Hohmann_Mercury.gif', 110],
  'Venus':['Estimated travel duration time: 15 months', './static/Hohmann_Venus.gif',90 ], 
  'Mars': ['Estimated travel duration time: 7 months','./static/Hohmann_Mars.gif', 160],
  'Jupiter': ['Estimated travel duration time: 6 years','./static/Hohmann_Jupiter.gif',300],
  'Saturn':['Estimated travel duration time: 7 years','./static/Hohmann_Saturn.gif',515],
  'Uranus':['Estimated travel duration time: 8.5 years','./static/Hohmann_Uranus.gif',800],
  'Neptune':['Estimated travel duration time: 12 years','./static/Hohmann_Neptune.gif',960]}

  prices = {'Economy':20, 'Business': 55, 'First': 70 }


  planet = 'Mars'
  price = "First"

  for i in planets.keys() and prices.keys() :
         if i == planet and i == price:
             sum = planets.get(i)[2] + prices.get(i)[0]
            print(sum)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using dictionaries is to avoid looping every time you want to do a lookup. If you want Mars info, ask for it. If you want first class info, ask for it:

```
planets[planet][2] + prices[price]
```

Using `get` will help you here not at all: you'll end up trying to add None and getting a misleading error message instead of a straightforward `KeyError` that tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Still got a KeyError . The Webapp cannot find Keys when planet  and prices are left out in blank in the form . 

I found a solution 

'def price(planet, seat): journey

   for i in planets.keys():
         if i == planet:
                 p = planets.get(i)[2]
                 for j in prices.keys():
                     if j == seat:
                         s = prices.get(j)
                         return(p + s)
I know is not a clean solution but it works'

Comment: @ed190. It only works if the key is present. `p + s` will raise an error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems it's as simple as

```
print(planets[planet][2] + prices[price])
```

That said, a few questions to hopefully help you understand what's wrong with your code:

- `for i in planets.keys() and prices.keys() :` what do you expect this to do?
- how could possibly `i` be equal to both `price` and `planet` in your second line, since `price` and `planet` are different?